# Getting a file list with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to list all the files in a specific directory on the server where my react is running. `fs` was removed from reactJS so I can't use that (I tried and it errors out). I'm not looking to do a file tree just get a list of files and maybe some basic info such as create/edit date. Everything I find via npm is a tree that needs that supplied but doesn't pull it.

Comment: https://github.com/diegohaz/list-react-files ?

Comment: fs was not removed from React, it was never part of it. It's part of the Node.js API, and if you import it with *const fs = require("fs")* it should work just fine.

Comment: Are you trying to do this client side or server side?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the relevant parts of your code? That would make it easier to understand the problem

Comment: @PatrickHund Not really a problem, more like a, "I can't figure out how to..."

Comment: @PatrickHund I tried that first and got the error `TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function`

Comment: Are you trying to do this compile-time or run-time? In compile-time I use webpack contexts to achieve that: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context. Something like `let context = require.context("./posts", true, /\.jsx/); context.keys().forEach(function(path) {let id = path.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d}; posts[id] = context(path); })`

Comment: @G_S I tried that andI get the same `TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function` since that package uses `fs`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue "TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function" And I can't get list-react-files to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

See [this ticket](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3074).

Comment: doing it that way I get the error, `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_fs__.readdir is not a function`

Comment: `fs` is a native node module and will not work on the browser. Browsers do not necessarily provide the same API.